# Android get data from Database to listview

Tags: php, android, sql

I have a database that has (name, sex, country) .. I want to get it's data and set it to a lsitview in android app.

How is that possible to be done?

- using php?
- using json?

I found about these in the internet, but couldn't really get to my point. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create some API for Android on server and transfer data in JSON. [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) is great tutorial about it.

Comment: This what I wanted, thanks.

Comment: @JohnJared I hope You will make it work. Please accept answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

write the code in `php` using pdo to retreive the table data and convert it into `json` using

json_encode();

use the `asynctask` in android to get the response from the web url;

use the `jsonObject` and `jsonarray` to get the data into array and add it into arraylist

create the array adapter and `setadapter` to the `listview`